# MySQL - Extracting Time in correct format

Tags: mysql, time

I have a table with a coloumn of type "time", and the values in this coloumn are stored as follows: 20:45:00, 18:00:00, etc.

Now when displaying the result, I am not getting the minutes, but just 00.
I am using the following to get the time:

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(time, '%h:%m') as time FROM ......... etc
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because %m answers against month - and not minutes. %i answers to minutes:

```
select
    time_format(`time`, '%H:%i') as time
from
    ...
```